# Creating GADT expression in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, gadt

There is my toy GADT expression:

```
type _ expr =
  | Num : int -> int expr
  | Add : int expr * int expr -> int expr
  | Sub : int expr * int expr -> int expr
  | Mul : int expr * int expr -> int expr
  | Div : int expr * int expr -> int expr
  | Lt  : int expr * int expr -> bool expr
  | Gt  : int expr * int expr -> bool expr
  | And : bool expr * bool expr -> bool expr
  | Or  : bool expr * bool expr -> bool expr
```

Evaluation function:

```
let rec eval : type a. a expr -> a = function
  | Num n -> n
  | Add (a, b) -> (eval a) + (eval b)
  | Sub (a, b) -> (eval a) - (eval b)
  | Mul (a, b) -> (eval a) * (eval b)
  | Div (a, b) -> (eval a) / (eval b)
  | Lt  (a, b) -> (eval a) < (eval b)
  | Gt  (a, b) -> (eval a) > (eval b)
  | And (a, b) -> (eval a) && (eval b)
  | Or  (a, b) -> (eval a) || (eval b)
```

Creating expression is trivial when we limited to `int expr`:

```
let create_expr op a b =
  match op with
  | '+' -> Add (a, b)
  | '-' -> Sub (a, b)
  | '*' -> Mul (a, b)
  | '/' -> Div (a, b)
  | _ -> assert false
```

The question is how to support both `int expr` and `bool expr` in `create_expr` function.

My try:

```
type expr' = Int_expr of int expr | Bool_expr of bool expr

let concrete : type a. a expr -> expr' = function
  | Num _ as expr -> Int_expr expr
  | Add _ as expr -> Int_expr expr
  | Sub _ as expr -> Int_expr expr
  | Mul _ as expr -> Int_expr expr
  | Div _ as expr -> Int_expr expr
  | Lt  _ as expr -> Bool_expr expr
  | Gt  _ as expr -> Bool_expr expr
  | And _ as expr -> Bool_expr expr
  | Or  _ as expr -> Bool_expr expr

let create_expr (type a) op (a:a expr) (b:a expr) : a expr =
  match op, concrete a, concrete b with
  | '+', Int_expr  a, Int_expr  b -> Add (a, b)
  | '-', Int_expr  a, Int_expr  b -> Sub (a, b)
  | '*', Int_expr  a, Int_expr  b -> Mul (a, b)
  | '/', Int_expr  a, Int_expr  b -> Div (a, b)
  | '<', Int_expr  a, Int_expr  b -> Lt  (a, b)
  | '>', Int_expr  a, Int_expr  b -> Gt  (a, b)
  | '&', Bool_expr a, Bool_expr b -> And (a, b)
  | '|', Bool_expr a, Bool_expr b -> Or  (a, b)
  | _ -> assert false
```

It still can't return value of generalized type.

> Error: This expression has type `int expr`
>          but an expression was expected of type `a expr`
>          Type `int` is not compatible with type `a`

### UPDATE

Thanks to @gsg, I was able to implement type safe evaluator. Two tricks are crucial there:

- existential wrapper `Any`
- type tagging (`TyInt` and `TyBool`) that lets us to pattern match `Any` type

see

```
type _ ty =
  | TyInt : int ty
  | TyBool : bool ty

type any_expr = Any : 'a ty * 'a expr -> any_expr

let create_expr op a b =
  match op, a, b with
  | '+', Any (TyInt,  a), Any (TyInt,  b) -> Any (TyInt,  Add (a, b))
  | '-', Any (TyInt,  a), Any (TyInt,  b) -> Any (TyInt,  Sub (a, b))
  | '*', Any (TyInt,  a), Any (TyInt,  b) -> Any (TyInt,  Mul (a, b))
  | '/', Any (TyInt,  a), Any (TyInt,  b) -> Any (TyInt,  Div (a, b))
  | '<', Any (TyInt,  a), Any (TyInt,  b) -> Any (TyBool, Lt  (a, b))
  | '>', Any (TyInt,  a), Any (TyInt,  b) -> Any (TyBool, Gt  (a, b))
  | '&', Any (TyBool, a), Any (TyBool, b) -> Any (TyBool, And (a, b))
  | '|', Any (TyBool, a), Any (TyBool, b) -> Any (TyBool, Or  (a, b))
  | _, _, _ -> assert false

let eval_any : any_expr -> [> `Int of int | `Bool of bool] = function
  | Any (TyInt, expr) -> `Int (eval expr)
  | Any (TyBool, expr) -> `Bool (eval expr)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you've found, this approach doesn't type check. It also has a more fundamental problem: GADTs can be recursive, in which case it is flatly impossible to enumerate their cases.

Instead you can reify types as a GADT and pass them around. Here's a cut-down example:

```
type _ expr =
  | Num : int -> int expr
  | Add : int expr * int expr -> int expr
  | Lt  : int expr * int expr -> bool expr
  | And : bool expr * bool expr -> bool expr

type _ ty =
  | TyInt : int ty
  | TyBool : bool ty

let bin_op (type a) (type b) op (l : a expr) (r : a expr) (arg_ty : a ty) (ret_ty : b ty) : b expr =
  match op, arg_ty, ret_ty with
  | '+', TyInt, TyInt -> Add (l, r)
  | '<', TyInt, TyBool -> Lt (l, r)
  | '&', TyBool, TyBool -> And (l, r)
  | _, _, _ -> assert false
```

At some point you are going to want to have a value that can be 'any expression'. Introducing an existential wrapper allows this. Cheesy example: generating random expression trees:

```
type any_expr = Any : _ expr -> any_expr

let rec random_int_expr () =
  if Random.bool () then Num (Random.int max_int)
  else Add (random_int_expr (), random_int_expr ())

let rec random_bool_expr () =
  if Random.bool () then Lt (Num (Random.int max_int), Num (Random.int max_int))
  else And (random_bool_expr (), random_bool_expr ())

let random_expr () =
  if Random.bool () then Any (random_int_expr ())
  else Any (random_bool_expr ())
```

Comment: Hmm... it is still not that clear. `bin_op '+' (Num 5) (Num 3)` call gives me `- : int ty -> '_a ty -> '_a expr = <fun>`. So, how can I use `bin_op`?

Comment: `bin_op '+' (Num 1) (Num 2) TyInt TyInt`

Comment: OK, I see. I need to explicitly specify arg and return types there. To make `bin_op` really useful, it is necessary to use existential wrapper anyway.

GADTs still look pretty confusing to me, because they implicitly mix compile time and run time stuff imho. Is there some "must read" paper on GADTs that may help?

Comment: I found GADTs confusing too, and explanatory examples have an unfortunate tendency to tend to gloss over the difficulties. I'm afraid I don't know of any particularly good material.

Answer (score 0):

Your stated type for `create_expr` is `char -> 'a expr -> 'a expr -> 'a expr`. But the type for the `'>'` case would be `char -> int expr -> int expr -> bool expr`. So it seems there are problems with the basic plan.

In essence you want the type of the result to depend on the value of the character. I'm not absolutely positive, but I suspect this isn't possible in OCaml. Seems like it would require a more powerful type system.