# Writing an interpreter with OCaml GADTs

Tags: ocaml, interpreter, type-systems, gadt

I am writing a small interpreter in OCaml and am using GADTs to type my expressions:

```
type _ value =
    | Bool : bool -> bool value
    | Int : int -> int value
    | Symbol : string -> string value
    | Nil : unit value
    | Pair : 'a value * 'b value -> ('a * 'b) value
and _ exp =
    | Literal : 'a value -> 'a exp
    | Var : name -> 'a exp
    | If : bool exp * 'a exp * 'a exp -> 'a exp
and name = string

exception NotFound of string

type 'a env = (name * 'a) list
let bind (n, v, e) = (n, v)::e
let rec lookup = function
    | (n, []) -> raise (NotFound n)
    | (n, (n', v)::e') -> if n=n' then v else lookup (n, e')

let rec eval : type a. a exp -> a value env -> a value = fun e rho ->
    match e with
    | Literal v -> v
    | Var n -> lookup (n, rho)
    | If (b, l, r) ->
            let Bool b' = eval b rho in
            if b' then eval l rho else eval r rho
```

But I cannot get my code to compile. I get the following error:

```
File "gadt2.ml", line 33, characters 33-36:
Error: This expression has type a value env = (name * a value) list
       but an expression was expected of type
         bool value env = (name * bool value) list
       Type a is not compatible with type bool
```

My understanding is that for some reason `rho` is being coerced into a `bool value env`, but I don't know why. I also tried the following:

```
let rec eval : 'a. 'a exp -> 'a value env -> 'a value = fun e rho ->
    match e with
    | Literal v -> v
    | Var n -> lookup (n, rho)
    | If (b, l, r) ->
            let Bool b = eval b rho in
            if b then eval l rho else eval r rho
```

But I am not sure how exactly that is different, and it also gives me an error -- albeit a different one:

```
File "gadt2.ml", line 38, characters 56-247:
Error: This definition has type bool exp -> bool value env -> bool value
       which is less general than 'a. 'a exp -> 'a value env -> 'a value
```

Guidance on GADTs, differences between the two `eval`s, and this particular problem are all appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30429552/creating-gadt-expression-in-ocaml as an example of type erasure and recovery

Comment: @Stas also the standard one: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extn.html#sec242

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type `'a env` is intended to represent a list of name/value bindings, but the values in a list must all be the same type. Two different value types (such as `bool value` and `int value`) are not the same type. If `eval b rho` returns `Bool b`, `rho` must be a list of `string * bool value`. So `eval l rho` and `eval r rho` will return `bool value`. But your annotation says the function returns `a value`.

Comment: Oh. In retrospect this seems obvious. Is there a standard way to handle this? Or, if I plan on typechecking, to guarantee that the types will work out?

Comment: @tekknolagi the standard way it to create a type box_value that will contain a `'a type * 'a value`, this way you can store all your values of different types in a list while transporting a proof of type with it.

Comment: What @Patj said - when you eval something you make it so you get back type `box_val` which you pattern match on. if the type you get back was a bool, then you go on your merry way and evaluate left or right. But if it *wasn't* a bool (someone put a nonboolean expression inside the if parens), then you print or otherwise propagate an error message (i'm not sure what OCaml supports in terms of exceptions - in Haskell I might do this in the `Either` monad).

Comment: @KarlC Exceptions handle this pretty well. Some people prefer an error/either monad, though monads are not as handy in OCaml as they are in Haskell (no higher order polymorphism and typeclass fancyness).

Comment: @PatJ is this notably different, then, to just using a standard ADT? At least for my case?

Comment: Note that you can use the `hmap` library, instead of reinventing this kind of things.

Comment: @tekknolagi It allows you to ensure that an `'a exp` can only return `'a` (or fail). How useful it is to you will depend on what you exactly want to do with your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible approaches to typed binding with GADTs. Here's a design that associates type info with both variables and environment entries.

Environment lookup involves attempting to construct a correspondence between the types of the variable and the environment entry (which is a bit slow, but does recover the type in a safe way). This is what allows the lookup to return an unwrapped value of arbitrary type.

```
type var = string

type _ ty =
  | TyInt : int ty
  | TyArrow : 'a ty * 'b ty -> ('a -> 'b) ty

type _ term =
  | Int : int -> int term
  | Var : 'a ty * var -> 'a term
  | Lam : 'a ty * var * 'b term -> ('a -> 'b) term
  | App : ('a -> 'b) term * 'a term -> 'b term

type ('a, 'b) eq = Refl : ('a, 'a) eq

let rec types_equal : type a b . a ty -> b ty -> (a, b) eq option =
  fun a b ->
    match a, b with
    | TyInt, TyInt -> Some Refl
    | TyArrow (x1, y1), TyArrow (x2, y2) ->
      begin match types_equal x1 x2, types_equal y1 y2 with
        | Some Refl, Some Refl -> Some Refl
        | _, _ -> None
      end
    | _, _ -> None

type env = Nil | Cons : var * 'a ty * 'a * env -> env

let rec lookup : type a . a ty -> var -> env -> a =
  fun ty var -> function
    | Nil -> raise Not_found
    | Cons (xname, xty, x, rest) ->
      if var = xname then
        match types_equal ty xty with
        | Some Refl -> x
        | None -> assert false
      else
        lookup ty var rest

let rec eval : type a . env -> a term -> a =
  fun env -> function
    | Int n -> n
    | Var (ty, var) -> lookup ty var env
    | App (f, x) -> (eval env f) (eval env x)
    | Lam (arg_ty, arg_name, body) ->
      fun arg_value ->
        eval (Cons (arg_name, arg_ty, arg_value, env)) body
```

It is possible to have a typed interpreter that avoids the type reconstruction (and the string comparison!) by enforcing the correspondence between variable indices and environments at the type level, but that gets complicated.