# Using GADT variants in a polymorphic, compound type as I would normal algebraic variant types?

Tags: polymorphism, ocaml, algebraic-data-types, gadt

Let's say I have this simple variant-type:

```
type flag = {
  name: string;
  payload: string option;
}

type word =
 | Arg of string
 | Flag of flag

let args = [|
  Arg "hello";
  Flag {name = "foo"; payload = Some "world"};
|]
```

If, however, I want to add GADT-constraints to that `word` type,

```
type _ word =
 | Arg : string -> string word
 | Flag : flag -> flag word
```

… the compiler can no longer infer a general type for the members of `args`:

```
Line 12, 3:
  This expression has type flag word
       but an expression was expected of type string word
       Type flag is not compatible with type string
```

Is this simply a limitation of GADTs?

Comment: you just don't need GADTs in your case. It is not a limitation of GADTs, but a feature :) Look at that experiment (building type safe evaluator) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30429552/creating-gadt-expression-in-ocaml

Answer (score 2):

I'm certainly no expert on GADTs, but this seems more like a limitation of ordinary type variables than of GADTs. `flag word` and `string word` are distinct types that won't fit into the same array no matter what.

I assume what you want is an existentially quantified type variable. If so the existential type variable should only occur on the left side of the arrow. This seems to work:

```ml
type word =
 | Arg : string -> word
 | Flag : flag -> word
```

Or in the words of [the manual](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extn.html#sec252):

> Variables are made existential when they appear inside a constructor’s argument, but not in its return type.

---

Edit: Nope, as @octachron points out in a comment, this is not how existential types work. Or rather existential type *variables*, of which there are none in my example. The cause is the same, but I'm not entirely clear on what property of a GADT is desired here and what therefore the solution would be.

Comment: Note that your type `word` is equivalent to the classical variant `type word = Arg of string | Flag of flag` since there is no type *variables* in the constructor definitions. An existential quantification would be more akin to `type dyn_word = Dyn: 'a word -> dyn_word` where `'a` is existentially quantified .

Comment: @octachron Right, lol, of course :) It's not entirely clear to me what purpose OP had in mind for using a GADT then.

Comment: See the post — I *started* with a classical variant, and tried to add a GADT constraint to it! As for the goal, it's simply to experiment with GADTs, start to get a feel for when I would use them in practice, see what restrictions they add. No particular goal. 

Answer (score 1):

It is not so much a limitation of GADTs than one of their desired properties. When you write

```
type _ word =
| Arg : string -> string word
| Flag : flag -> flag word
```

you are asking the typechecker to make the type of `Arg _` and `Flag _` different and incompatible.

To motivate this behavior, a better example might be a list with a static length:

```
 type zero = Zero
 type 'a succ = Succ
 type ('elt,'size) nlist =
 | []: ('elt, zero) nlist
 | (::): 'elt * ('elt, 'size) nlist ->  ('elt, 'size succ) nlist
```

With this definition a value of type `('n, 's) nlist` carries an encoding of its length inside this type. This makes it possible to write a total `hd` function

```
  let hd (a::q) = a
```

Since our exotic list type carries its length in its type, the typechecker can express the fact that `hd` only accepts list with one or more argument (i.e. the type of hd is 
`('elt,_ succ) nlist -> 'elt`). Thus the function `hd` always returns (when its type checks).

But this also means that the type checker must now enforce than the function `hd` always works. In other words, an array mixing length of different size

```
  [| []; [1]; [1;2] |]
```

cannot be allowed to type-check because it contains element for which the `hd` function is not well-defined and the type checker guaranteed to us earlier than `hd` will always return a successful value.

Returning to your example, with your type definition, you have made it possible to discriminate between `Flag _` and `Int _`. Thus I can write the following total function

```
 let empty (Arg _) = ""
 let map_empty = Array.map empty
```

and expect than `map_empty` works on all well-typed arrays. But I cannot possibly apply this function to your mixed array

```
 let args = [|
   Arg "hello";
   Flag {name = "foo"; payload = Some "world"};
 |]
```

In other words, this array cannot be well-typed.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to handle this situation with GADTs is to introduce existential wrappers (here, `any_word`):

```
type flag = {
  name : string;
  payload : string option;
}

type _ word =
  | Arg : string -> string word
  | Flag : flag -> flag word

type any_word = Word : _ word -> any_word [@@unboxed]

let args = [|
  Word (Arg "hello");
  Word (Flag {name = "foo"; payload = Some "world"});
|]
```

`args` contains `word`s of unknown type index, that index being hidden inside the `any_word` wrapper. In contrast,

```
let flag_args = [|
  Flag {name = "zonk"; payload = None};
  Flag {name = "splines"; payload = Some "reticulate"};
|]
```

`flag_args` contains `flag word`s specifically. `string word`s are excluded by the type system, which is one of the attractions of GADTs. (If you don't need this, GADTs are not likely to be helpful.)